# Why can't the php interpreter not parse unset call after &&?

Tags: php, interpreter

While writing a function to sanitize a configuration array, I noticed that it is not possible to call unset after `&&`.Now I'm curious. What is the difference between unset and the call of any other function? 
For example, the first short-if is completely valid the second one will throw a parser exception.

```
<?php

$a = ['test' => 1];

isset($a['test']) && test();
isset($a['test']) && unset($a['test']) ;

function test(){
    return 123;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps more information on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476028/is-this-special-treatment-of-exit-and-die-documented-in-phpm especially the part about *Here are the interesting few which do not return a value, and therefore are not expressions*.

Comment: Thx for digging up this post. This is very interesting and does indeed answer my question.